# jsPDF from table with mixed image & text content

Tags: jspdf

I have been spending a lot of time working with jsPDF trying to create a pdf doc that uses a table with images in some cells and text in other cells.  I am misunderstanding something critical.  Even though I am converting the images to data urls, the images are not appearing in the final PDF.  I have also tried **.fromHTML** but the resulting page is blank.

The only thing i can get to work so far is a straight, single column of divs with only a single item in each div.  Using .fromHTML works in this way, but it doesn't seem to work with more than one div side-by-side limiting my ability to include a graphic border around the dynamic content in the middle of the doc, which is retrieved from URL-encoded pairs in the address.

So I've been trying to do it with a table instead.  Here's a picture of what I am trying to achieve. [Certificate Sliced](http://marsinc.com/clients/nfpa/certificate/certificatesliced.jpg)  .  This is exported out of Photoshop using slices (shown). The table is quite simple, although it does have some colspans which could be part of my problem. I then used [DataURL Maker](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) to encode the graphic parts, and leaving the middle cells that have text-only alone as html text.

Here's the table as output from Photoshop (with original image links):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Certificate 2015-table</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (Certificate 2015-table.psd) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="997" height="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><img src="images/small-table_01.png" width="997" height="222" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_02.png" width="86" height="46" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_03.png" width="826" height="46" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_04.png" width="85" height="46" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_05.png" width="86" height="45" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_06.png" width="826" height="45" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_07.png" width="85" height="45" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_08.png" width="86" height="74" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_09.png" width="826" height="74" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_10.png" width="85" height="74" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_11.png" width="86" height="75" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_12.png" width="826" height="75" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_13.png" width="85" height="75" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_14.png" width="86" height="56" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_15.png" width="826" height="56" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_16.png" width="85" height="56" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_17.png" width="86" height="54" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_18.png" width="826" height="54" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_19.png" width="85" height="54" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_20.png" width="565" height="99" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_21.jpg" width="255" height="19" alt=""></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><img src="images/small-table_22.png" width="177" height="99" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_23.png" width="255" height="22" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/small-table_24.png" width="255" height="58" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><img src="images/small-table_25.png" width="997" height="78" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="86" height="1" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="479" height="1" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="255" height="1" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="92" height="1" alt=""></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="85" height="1" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```

The goal of course will be to have a single certificate that can be customized for each student and each course that can be downloadable as PDF.  Is it possible to include pictures in cells of a table and save with jsPDF?

Thanks for any help,
--Kevin